# Работа с combobox в Delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-10.3-rio

В базе данных есть таблица со вторичными ключами. На форме соответственно вторичные ключи выводятся в комбобоксы и заполняются, при этом после заполнения активный индекс в комбобоксе должен становится то значение, которое соответствует данной строке. Пример кода когда то работал, но спустя 2 года я не могу уже это повторить, ничего не понимаю, что я пропустил, он постоянно делает активным не то что нужно. Я никак не могу сопоставить индексы combobox с id вторичного ключа.

```
type_ob:=tstringlist.Create;
adotable2.Active:=true;
while not adotable2.eof do
begin
  type_ob.Add(adotable2name_type_ob.value);
  adotable2.Next;
end;
Combobox2.Items.AddStrings(type_ob);
Combobox2.ItemIndex:=0;

showdata;
```

Процедура showdata

```
i:=ADOQuery2id_type_ob.value;
Combobox2.text:=(i);
```

Comment: `DBComboBox` или `DBLookupComboBox` не для этого случайно предназначены?

Comment: Преподаватель не разрешает пользоваться ни dbgri, ни dbedit, только коннектор и квери.

Comment: Вроде это строчка Combobox2.ItemIndex:=0 всегда делает активным первый элемент из списка items в комбобоксе...;  и еще проверить бы что в нем точно есть items, что бы не поймать крах при исполнении...

Comment: Я разобрался, этот код актуален только в том случае если id в базе данных идет по порядку. И соотвественно в showdata i нужно вычесть 1 так как индексы в combobox с 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В нулевой индекс combobox прописываю строку то что мне необходимо, например фамилию какого нибудь человека из базы данных.
Для того чтобы достать его id в запросе изменения/удаление всей таблицы я делаю запрос селект в таблицу этих людей и там выбираю select id where name='+ combobox.text +'
А потом полученный id использую в запросе со вторичными ключами